# Using x:key attribute with DataTemplate from Resources in XAML control definition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have WPF Application called `Designer`, where `MainWindow` (derived from `Window`) and `GraphControl` (derived from `UserControl`) classes are placed in `Designer` Assembly (which is set as startup project). Application uses a few other assemblies, amongst them `GraphModel` assembly, which contains view models for used controls.

I have few `DataTemplate` declarations in `GraphControl.xaml`, i.e (listing simplified):

```
<UserControl x:Class="Designer.GraphControl"
       xmlns:GraphModel="clr-namespace:GraphModel;assembly=GraphModel">

  <UserControl.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>

      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type GraphModel:NodeViewModel}">

        <!-- (...) -->

      </DataTemplate>

    </ResourceDictionary>

  </UserControl.Resources>

</UserControl>
```

Application `Designer` works properly, as it was invented. Afterwards, I have created new `Visual Studio Package` project, to make a custom editor for VS2012, and I need to use my `GraphControl` from `Designer` assembly in `Package` project. I have noticed that my trial of incorporate WPF control within `Package` project cause exception:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
  Message=Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=0
  LinePosition=0
  InnerException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
       Source=mscorlib
       Message=Could not load file or assembly 'GraphModel, PublicKeyToken=c2639211081ade27' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Thereafter, I found that if I add `x:key` attribute to above `DataTemplate` element, above mentioned exception is not raised and control is displayed in `Designer` Application and in `Package` Application, but UI Element (`NodeItem` control) that is represented by `NodeViewModel` is not displayed on the screen, but I see only a weird small control looks like `TextBlock` with *GraphModel.NodeViewModel* text, instead of original `NodeItem` control. It happens bot in `Designer` and `Package` Applications.

My question is: What am I doing wrong and how should I repair a code to have working control in both Applications. Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added reference to `GraphModel` assembly from `Package` project? How do you try to use it in that app? You have upload empty user control, could you upload also a part with Items source. I'm asking it because items which you pass to `GraphControl` must be `GraphModel:NodeViewModel` type for applying that template.

To my opinion it works wit `x:Key` only because, you don't use it in application (that key can be used only in `GraphControl` with `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource`, because you declared DataTemplate on `GraphControl` resource level). So in result you have small items without your template, and no need in the `GraphModel:NodeViewModel` occurs.

Comment: Yes, I have added a reference to `GraphModel` project from `Package` project. In `Designer` App, I add a control to `MainWindow` using XAML markup, in `Package` App I use helper `WpfEditorPane` class (derived from `WindowPane`, `IVsPersistDocData`), as it is described there : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704920/visual-studio-how-to-write-editor-extensions-with-wpf). Without `x:key` attribute, `Designer` App work properly, but `Package` raises exception. With this attribute, `Designer` and `Package` (no exception) show control, but with UI Element with default template(TextBlock).

Comment: I will upload more source code soon, because at now I don't have it on current machine.

Comment: In regard of items source of `GraphControl`. I don't pass any items to this control. Elements of type `GraphModel:NodeViewModel` are create by control's code behind, due to events from user interface (commands bound to context menu associated with control). I think the problem is that element from `ResourceDictionary` (DataTemplate in that case) becomes unaccessible within the parent assembly and from external assembly after the `x:key` attribute is set.

Comment: Sorry, but second paragraph of your answer is fairly unclear for me. It does not work with `x:key`. Therefore, what is a solution?