# How to create Visual Studio 2012 WPF custom designer/editor

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I have created WPF Application which allows user to create a graph with the aid of visual tools. This application is able to serialize graph layout, attributes and data to XML file, and then it can deserialize XML content, rebuild graph, and show visualization to the user.

I need to integrate this application with Visual Studio 2012, as extension or plugin, to have a possibility to open, modify and save files from Solution Explorer with specific extensions using my graph designer. It's conceptually similar to Entity Framework Designer for Visual Studio.

I have installed Visual Studio SDK to write VS Package. I created `Visual Studio Package` project, then I selected "Custom Editor" option. Some sample code was generated, but it uses Windows Form control. It looks like it is hard to incorporate WPF control with VS "Custom Editor" interfaces.

How can I create custom VS2012 WPF designer? I can't find any good documentation or tutorial on the Web to target my requirements. I have already a complete WPF Application, with functionality of creating graph using GUI tool, serializing and deserializing to file. I just need to integrate it with Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, i believe the OP is quite aware of that since they: a) Linked that very question and b) Put a bounty on it... But still, it's not an exact duplicate, is it...

Comment: @StefanDenchev - I'm 100% sure is fully aware of that too. This is just to not leave questions open. IMHO it's a complete duplicate, but the OP can comment on this.

Comment: @SimonMourier Indeed, i didn't read the other question completely (sorry) and i have to agree they are close enough to be considered duplicates.

Comment: Indeed, my question seems to be duplicate. It has related questions with some answers linked, so should be closed. But it should be mentioned that gratifying answer was made after I created this question and set bounty on related question.